# Reading from list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to read from a list in python using while loops but I just can't seem to get it. I keep getting list index out of range errors.

This is the list:

```
names = [['Bilbo', 'Baggins'], ['Gollum'], ['Tom', 'Bombadil'], ['Aragorn']]
```

Instead of using for loops for:

```
for person in people:     
    to_print = "" 
    for name in person: 
        to_print += name + " " 
    print(to_print)
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Protip: Don't use while loops to get data out of lists. Use for loops: `for name in names: print(name[0])`

Comment: remember that indexes are between 0 and `len(names)-1` inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent `while` loop version of your `for` loop code is:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> while i < len(names):
        j = 0
        to_print = ""
        while j < len(names[i]):
            to_print += names[i][j] + " "
            j += 1
        print(to_print)
        i += 1


Bilbo Baggins 
Gollum 
Tom Bombadil 
Aragorn
```

And a better version of the `for` loop code is:

```
>>> for person in names:
        print(' '.join(person))


Bilbo Baggins
Gollum
Tom Bombadil
Aragorn
```

Comment: Ok awesome thanks. I can see exactly where I was going wrong now. Thanks soo much

Answer (score 1):

To use Python lists, you don't need indexes.

```
for bunch_of_names in names:
    if len(bunch_of_names) > 1: # e.g. bunch_of_names = ['Bilbo', 'Baggins']
        print 'First name:', bunch_of_names[0], 'Last name: ', bunch_of_names[1]
    else: # e.g. ['Aragorn']
        print 'Name: ', bunch_of_names[0] # the only one
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
for name in names:
   for subname in name:
       print(subname)
```

Comment: I need to use while loops. The original thing was to convert from for loops to while loops

Comment: @user2322049 You haven't even explained what you are trying to do